# How to use a KeyValueStore state store in DSL?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

```
KeyValueStore<String, Long> kvStore=(KeyValueStore<String, Long>) 
Stores.create("InterWindowStore1").withKeys(Serdes.String())
                .withValues(Serdes.Long())
                .persistent()
                .build().get();`
```

I have created statestore as shown in above code and try to insert into `kvStore.put(key, value);` but it is throwing me NPE

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.put(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:117)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ForwardingCacheFlushListener.apply(ForwardingCacheFlushListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.maybeForward(CachingWindowStore.java:103)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore.access$200(CachingWindowStore.java:34)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingWindowStore$1.apply(CachingWindowStore.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:131)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:95)
```

Comment: this looks ok. are you sure that the `kvStore ` is not null at the point of invocation or key/value is not null ?

Comment: Yes both kvstore and key,value are not null

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the overall scenario, as you title says "without adding to any processor" -- you you try to call "put()" from "outside" of your Kafka Streams application? Stores a not designed for this usage. (Could not track the NPE in details, as I am not sure what version you are using and in 0.10.2 the line shown in the stack trace seems to never throw an NPE). -- So what do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: In low level api usage i have seen using `this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Integer>) context.getStateStore("Counts");` where context is the processor to which statestore is added . I just want  to leverage the fault tolerance  ability of statestore by using it to store key value pair. My Stream version is 0.10.1.1 .

Comment: In order to avoid duplicate window which is caused due to a kafka stream commit , I have used window.overlap to check for the duplicate window and update the value of the window. Example : My window(windowing period of 5 mints) was started at 5:10pm but a commit has happened at 5:12pm the the window has a value of 10 is pushed to the topic . Now commit has been completed , so window resumes and at 5:15 the value is 25  which will be pushed to topic. Here window value is 25 but it is pushed to topic at commit with , so i trying to use window lap and pushing the window value as 15(25-10)to topic

Comment: In order to achieve this i am trying store window and it value in statestore. So i want to use statestore so that it provides fault tolerance to window key value pair.

Comment: This make sense, but I am still not sure what you mean by "without adding to any processor". Added an answer for the what I would do.

Comment: removed "without adding to any processor"(i used this bcz i thought statestore can be used only when we add it to a processor) from title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe in your comments you are basically doing a window aggregation:

```java
KStream stream = ...
KTable table = stream.groupByKey().aggregate(..., TimeWindow.of(...));
```

As you `KTable` stream might contain updates for you window aggregation, you want to modify this stream. For this, you can use a stateful transformer or value-transformer:

```java
StateStoreSupplier myState = State.create("nameOfMyState")....;

KStream result = table.toStream().transform(..., "nameOfMyState");
```

Finally, you can write your result to the output topic:

```java
result.to("output-topic");
```

Your `Transformer` that you provide to `transform` can get the state via the given context in `init()` and use within `transform()` each time a window output is generated/updated.